# Launch java processes upon docker run command

Tags: linux, docker, selenium-grid

I have a docker image with custom files and binaries. I want to be able to run a docker container with this image and start 2 java processes upon starting the container.

Currently I'm doing it manually:

```
docker run -i -t -p 4444:4444 6b23ccf3402c
```

Then, after I'm inside my container I'm launching my java processes:

```
java -jar /app/grid/hint-selenium-server-standalone-1.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar -role hub -hubConfig /app/grid/hubConfig.json -log /app/grid/logs/hub.log &

java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/app/node/drivers/chromedriver -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/app/node/drivers/geckodriver -Dphantomjs.binary.path=/app/node/drivers/phantomjs -jar /app/node/hint-selenium-server-standalone-1.0.6-jar-with-dependencies.jar -role node -hub http://172.17.0.2:4444/grid/register/ -nodeConfig /app/node/nodeConfig.json -log /app/node/logs/node.log &
```

My question is, how can I do it in one "docker run" command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with:

```
docker run -i -t -p 4444:4444 6b23ccf3402c bash -c "java -jar [...] & java -jar [...] & bash"
```

But you could also use the [CMD statement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) inside the Dockerfile

```
CMD java -jar [...] & java -jar [...] & bash
```

And than run `docker run -it 6b23ccf3402c`